# Recovering from an EventStoreException where sequence is already in use within DeadlineHandler

Tags: exception, axon

Sometime an EventStoreException occurs mentioning the event couldn't be stored because it has the same sequence as another event in the aggregate.

This happens when EventA and EventB almost have the same timestamp.
CommandA is sent by a controller and CommandB is sent by a Saga within a DeadlineHandler.

So the handling of the deadline fails with the EventStoreException is logged, but not retried.
Would it help if we configure the Saga with a PropagatingErrorHandler?

Events table:

```
timestamp                      | aggregate_id                         | seq | type
                               |                                      |     |
2020-11-30T15:14:51.345541552Z | b02a5364-ee34-431a-ab1a-6c59bb937845 | 0   | MyAggregate
2020-11-30T15:14:52.06794746Z  | b02a5364-ee34-431a-ab1a-6c59bb937845 | 1   | MyAggregate
```

Exception details:

```java
org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EventStoreException: An event for aggregate [b02a5364-ee34-431a-ab1a-6c59bb937845] at sequence [1] was already inserted

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO events 
(event_id, aggregate_id, sequence_number, type, timestamp, payload_type, payload_revision, payload, metadata) 
VALUES 
('d5be369e-5fd0-475e-b5b6-e12449a4ed04',
'b02a5364-ee34-431a-ab1a -6c59bb937845',
1,
'MyAggregate',
'2020-11-30T15:14:52.067871723Z',
'MyEvent',
NULL,
'{"payload":"payload"}',
'{"metaData":"metaData"}') 
was aborted: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_aggregate_identifier_sequence_number"
  Detail: Key (aggregate_id, sequence_number)=(b02a5364-ee34-431a-ab1a-6c59bb937845, 1) already exists.
```

As you can see the timestamp of the events are nearly the same:
`EventA: 2020-11-30T15:14:52.06794746Z` vs. `EventB: 2020-11-30T15:14:52.067871723Z`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To first answer your question, confiruging a `PropagatingErrorHandler` does not help because `TrackingEventProcessor` is not going to retry a `DeadlineMessage`. It only works for retrying real events which is not the case dor a `DeadlineMessage` since it is not an Event.

Now to your problem, we are assuming that your Saga has a `DeadlineHandler` and this component is dispatching a `Command` towards your `Aggregate` at the same time another component is also dispatching a `Command` to the same `Aggregate`. In that way, the `Aggregate` is failing to handle the second `Command`.
Based on that, we can give you 2 advices:

- Have a consistent [Routing Strategy](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/implementations#distributing-the-command-bus) which is used by a Distributed implementation of the `CommandBus`. In short, it will give you the following:

> Two commands with the same routing key will always be routed to the same segment.

- Have a `RetryScheduler` configured on your `CommandGateway`. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/implementations#the-command-gateway).

> The RetryScheduler is capable of scheduling retries when command execution has failed.